woocommerce api error JSON ERROR: Invalid JSON returned
I'm loading product information automatically through the woocommerce V3 product api. It works fine for the most part, but the odd time I will get a "411" "Invalid JSON Returned" even on identical calls.
Its intermittent and it doesn't provide any more information then that. I've checked the JSON args and they are identical to ones that work. I've validated the JSON syntax, no issues. If I run the same thing again, sometimes it loads without that error.
Not sure if anyone has seen this before and can provide insight?
